# pybarcode add not setted digits

Tags: python, barcode

I try to generate barcode EAN13 (1234567890123)

```
ean = barcode.get('ean13', '1234567890123')
return render(request, 'index.html', {'date':now, 'data': listing, 'auth': auth, 'barcode': ean})
```

in template add

```
{{ barcode }}
```

and receive result as:

> 1234567890128

Why this strings is different (1234567890128 must have 1234567890123)?

Answer (score 0):

`1234567890123` is not a valid EAN code; even if you had managed to output that barcode, nothing would have been able to scan it, because its check digit is incorrect.  The barcode software you're using helpfully corrected the check digit, rather than producing a useless barcode (although generating an error might arguably have been a better thing for it to do).

Comment: Understand. Thank you